# LARAVEL 5.8 : Window onscroll, scroll not working in blade template

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

My laravel 5.8 app cannot use the scroll function and I don't know why.

My code is in `app.blade.php`

```
<script src="{{ asset('asset\js\jquery.min.js') }}"></script> // 3.3.1
.
.
<script>
   window.onscroll = function () {
    console.log('scroll')
   };
</script>
.
.
.
</body>
```

What I have tried

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(window).scroll(function() {
         console.log('scroll')
     }) 
 })
```

It is still not working. What did I do wrong?

Comment: is your jquery loaded properly ?

Comment: If your jquery loads perfectly it will definitely work !!

Comment: ctrl + u then  check jquery loaded or not first or alert something in $document ready to see jquery working or not

Answer (score 0):

try `scrollIntoView`

```js
function scrollToC() { divC.scrollIntoView(); }

window.onscroll = function () { console.log('scroll') };
```

```css
html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }
.block { height: 1000px; width: 300px; margin: 20px; background: yellow; )
```

```html
<button onclick="scrollToC()">Scroll to C</button>
<div id="divA" class="block">a</div>
<div id="divB" class="block">b</div>
<div id="divC" class="block">c</div>
```

Comment: It's scroll but not smooth and no console log.

Comment: @DonNoinongyao open chrome console to see log (I turn off snippet console because it broke the scroll - also scrolling inside snipped dont work very good (it scroll down stackOvefrlow window) - but it is smooth which means it animae (not jump immediatley) - however scroll smothness is not part of question - treat it like bonus)

Comment: Yes I use chrome dev tool to see js log and when I click the button, The function work but 'window.onscroll' did'nt work(no log in console).

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I believe OP only wants the onscroll event so I'm confused as to why you recommended `scrollIntoView` to him.

Comment: @DonNoinongyao it is very strange - when I click on button in snippet, in chrome dev console i see "scroll" (46 times) - this means that `window.onscroll` event handler was fired. Of course In this approach we use simple js (no jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your app.blade.php

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(window).scroll(function() {
                console.log('scrolled');
                console.log(window.pageYOffset);
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app" style="height:1000px;">
        <!-- your contents  -->
    </div>
</body>
```